# form.fill() not working in one project, works fine in another

Tags: java, html, forms, scala, playframework

I have 2 projects with the names:

- old
- new

I made a form in "old" with a radiobutton and some textfields to enter age, weight, ...
Then I made a new project (activator new new) and developed the form further. The controller pre-fills the form, pre-selects the radiobutton etc.
Now I wanted to update "old" and copied the code from "new" into "old".
In ALL controller-classes, in ALL model-classes, in ALL views-classes is the EXACT same code! I even checked the file sizes manually several times, BUT in "old" the form does not get pre-filled! No matter what I do, nothing happens. I have no clue why this happens and what do to.

My code:

**Application.java:**

```
package controllers;

import models.User;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class Application extends Controller {

    static Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class);

    public static Result index() {

        User user = new User();
        Form<User> preFilledForm = userForm.fill(user);

        return ok(views.html.index.render(preFilledForm));
    }
}
```

**User.java:**

```
package models;

public class User {
    public Integer gewicht;
    public Integer groesse;
    public Integer alter;

    public Float grundUmsatz;

    public String geschlecht = "Mann";

    public User(){
        gewicht = 0;
        groesse = 0;
        alter = 0;
        geschlecht = "Mann";
    }
}
```

**index.scala.html:**

```
@(userForm : Form[User])

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("App - index") {

    @helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit(), 'id -> "userForm"){
        <fieldset>
            @helper.inputRadioGroup(
            userForm("Geschlecht"),
            options = options("Mann"->"Mann","Frau"->"Frau"),
            '_label -> "Gender",
            '_error -> userForm("Geschlecht").error.map(_.withMessage("select gender"))
            )
        </fieldset>

        @helper.inputText(userForm("Gewicht"))
        @helper.inputText(userForm("Groesse"))
        @helper.inputText(userForm("Alter"))
        <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Send">
    }
}
```

**main.scala.html:**

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

**routes-file:**

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /auswertung/                controllers.Application.submit()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: I use Play 2.3.8 with the Scala IDE. I also tested the webpage in several browsers, cleaned the cache of the webrowsers, made "Clean projects" in eclipse, tried "activator eclipse", ... nothing helped so far.

Comment: Have you tried to execute `activator clean` followed by `activator run` and then open it in the browser?

Comment: Well ... that worked.
Seems like you should make pauses and stop sitting before your computer from time to time. Didnt think of "activator clean" it seems. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Peanut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596532/peanut) reminded me of `activator clean` and then `activator run`. Seems like I've worked too long on this to see the solution. Thank you for the reminder!